# How can I retain display precision when converting from scientific to decimal notation?

Tags: perl, precision

Consider the following float:

```
8.22120183514065e-05
```

Now obviously [`(s)printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) is the standard thing to do here, but `%f` alters its precision:

```
printf "%f", 8.22120183514065e-05;    # 0.000082
```

Using an arbitrarily large precision, say `%.30f`, adds additional digits (`...6505`):

```
printf "%.30f", 8.22120183514065e-05; # 0.000082212081351406505000000000
```

Is there a way to maintain the precision present in the scientific notation without knowing its exact precision in advance?

Comment: Um, no? The string `8.22120183514065e-05` is itself just a finite-precision representation of the "true" value represented, for example, in the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: Unless you are just asking about string manipulations of string values, in which case I withdraw my objection.

Comment: I take it you want to add the number in the exponent to the precision -- so if it's `e-05` you add five digits to what you'd normally have (15 by default).  If it's `e03` you'd add three, etc.  I don't see how to retrieve the would-be "exponent" without working it out by hand first.

Comment: Re "*Using an arbitrarily large precision adds additional digits*", No, it doesn't. That's the number that was actually stored since it was impossible to store 8.22120183514065e-05 exactly.

Comment: @ikegami I get that. I just don't want to see any more or any fewer digits than what the scientific notation has. Similar to what `%g` does, except that `%g` maintains scientific notation for the example shown; it doesn't convert it to decimal notation

Comment: There's no way to know how many digits the code literal had.

Comment: You're basically asking for something that doesn't make sense. You ask us to "consider the float `8.22120183514065e-05`" but that isn't a floating-point value: it's a string of characters. You may get a useful answer if you explain what you're trying to do with real-life examples, but unless the values you're dealing with are input as strings exactly as you show, and the precision of those values corresponds exactly to the number of digits in the string, then what you're hoping for is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to stringify a number such that the stringification has the same number of signficant digits as the code literal that produced the number.

That's impossible. The number of significant digits in the code literal that produced the number (if there even was such a literal) is not stored anywhere.

Simply put, there's no way to get

```
0.0000822120183514065
```

or even

```
8.22120183514065e-05
```

from the number

```
0.0000822120183514065132508730204818903075647540390491485595703125
```

from the available information.

---

It would be different if you started with the string

```
8.22120183514065e-05
```

or if you knew the desired precision such that you could create the above string using

```
sprintf('%.*e', $significant_digits-1, $n)
```

If you had this, you could perform string manipulations to move the `.` as needed.

```
$n =~ s/^\d\K\.// ? $n =~ s/^\d+\Ke([+-]\d+)\z// : $n =~ s/^\d\Ke([+-]\d+)\z// or die;
my $exp = $1 + 1;
if    ( $exp <= 0         ) { $n = '0.' . ( '0' x -$exp ) . $n;  }
elsif ( $exp < length($n) ) { substr($n, $exp, 0, '.');          }
elsif ( $exp > length($n) ) { $n .= '0' x ( $exp - length($n) ); }
```

---

```
$ perl -e'printf "%.70f\n", 8.22120183514065e-05;'
0.0000822120183514065132508730204818903075647540390491485595703125000000

$ perl -e'printf "%.70e\n", 8.22120183514065e-05;'
8.2212018351406513250873020481890307564754039049148559570312500000000000e-05

$ perl -e'printf "%.*e\n", 14, 8.22120183514065e-05;'
8.22120183514065e-05
```

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping for some sort of built-in, `sprintf`-y way to do this. Oh well.

Comment: From a number? The information isn't there. From a string? That could cause a loss of precision. Best to work with the string form. Solution added to answer.